# Having trouble with lock wait timeout errors

Tags: mysql, timeout

I have a procedure that will update some values in a table.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_TRX_DYNAMICPROD`(
IN sMethod varchar(30),
IN sStockCode varchar(20),
IN sIsActive varchar(6),
IN sStockDesc varchar(100),
IN sQTY decimal(15,3),
IN sUnitPrices VARCHAR(255),
IN sBuckets VARCHAR(255),
IN OriginalQTY VARCHAR(10),
IN Minimum1 VARCHAR(25),
IN Minimum2 VARCHAR(25),
IN Minimum3 VARCHAR(25),
IN sBy VARCHAR(10),
OUT Result varchar(30),
OUT Message varchar(30)
)
BEGIN
    IF sMethod = 'UPDATE_PRDPRICE' THEN
        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_result;
        -- Create a temporary table to hold the procedure result
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_result (
            spu_stockcode VARCHAR(16),
            spu_pricebucket VARCHAR(20),
            spu_uomcode VARCHAR(6),
            spu_unitprice DECIMAL(15,3),
            spu_qty DECIMAL(15,3)
        );

        -- Call the stored procedure and insert the result into the temporary table
        CALL SP_STRING_TO_ROWS(sUnitPrices, sBuckets, sStockCode, sStockDesc, sQTY);

        -- Update the table with the values from the temporary table
        IF (OriginalQTY = '"NULL"') THEN
            UPDATE stkm_stockpricesuom t
                JOIN temp_result tr ON t.spu_stockcode = tr.spu_stockcode
                AND t.spu_uomcode = tr.spu_uomcode
                JOIN stkm_pricebucket b ON t.spu_pricebucket = b.bucket_code
                AND tr.spu_pricebucket = b.bucket_desc
                SET t.spu_unitprice = tr.spu_unitprice,
                    t.spu_defaultprice = sIsActive,
                    t.spu_factor = tr.spu_qty,
                    t.modifiedby = sBy,
                    t.modifieddt = NOW()
                WHERE t.spu_factor = sQTY;
        ELSE
            UPDATE stkm_stockpricesuom t
                JOIN temp_result tr ON t.spu_stockcode = tr.spu_stockcode
                AND t.spu_uomcode = tr.spu_uomcode
                JOIN stkm_pricebucket b ON t.spu_pricebucket = b.bucket_code
                AND tr.spu_pricebucket = b.bucket_desc
                SET t.spu_unitprice = tr.spu_unitprice,
                    t.spu_defaultprice = sIsActive,
                    t.spu_factor = tr.spu_qty,
                    t.modifiedby = sBy,
                    t.modifieddt = NOW()
                WHERE t.spu_factor = CAST(OriginalQTY AS DECIMAL(15,3));
        END IF;


        -- Drop the temporary table
        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_result;

        SELECT '00000' INTO Result;
        SELECT 'Success Updated' INTO Message;

    END IF;

    IF sMethod = 'ADD_PRDPRICE' THEN
        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_result;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_result (
            spu_stockcode VARCHAR(16),
            spu_pricebucket VARCHAR(20),
            spu_uomcode VARCHAR(6),
            spu_unitprice DECIMAL(15,3),
            spu_qty DECIMAL(15,3)
        );

        CALL SP_STRING_TO_ROWS(sUnitPrices, sBuckets, sStockCode, sStockDesc, sQTY);

        INSERT INTO stkm_stockpricesuom (spu_stkprcidx, spu_pricebucket, spu_stockcode, spu_uomcode, recstatus, createdby, createddt, modifiedby, modifieddt, spu_unitprice, spu_factor, spu_effdate, spu_defaultprice)
        SELECT null, pb.bucket_code, temp.spu_stockcode, temp.spu_uomcode, 1, sBy, NOW(), "", null, temp.spu_unitprice, temp.spu_qty, NOW(), sIsActive
        FROM temp_result temp, stkm_pricebucket pb
        WHERE pb.bucket_desc = temp.spu_pricebucket;

        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_result;
        SELECT '00000' INTO Result;
        SELECT 'Success Updated' INTO Message;
    END IF;

    IF sMethod = 'DEL_PRDPRICE' THEN
        DELETE FROM stkm_stockpricesuom WHERE spu_stockcode = sStockCode AND spu_uomcode = sStockDesc AND spu_factor = sQTY;

        SELECT '00000' INTO Result;
        SELECT 'Success Updated' INTO Message;
    END IF;
      
    IF sMethod = 'MINPRC_STOCKMASTER' THEN
        -- SELECT SLEEP(25);
        -- KILL CONNECTION_ID()-1;

        IF (LENGTH(Minimum1) > 0) THEN
            UPDATE stkm_stockmaster SET stk_minprice = Minimum3, stk_minpricesuom = Minimum2, stk_minpricebase = Minimum1 WHERE stk_stockcode = sStockCode;
            
            SELECT '00000' INTO Result;
            SELECT 'Success Updated' INTO Message;
        ELSE
            UPDATE stkm_stockmaster SET stk_minprice = 0.000, stk_minpricesuom = Minimum2, stk_minpricebase = Minimum1 WHERE stk_stockcode = sStockCode;

            SELECT '00000' INTO Result;
            SELECT 'Success Updated' INTO Message;
        END IF;
    END IF;

END
```

How the procedure works is the web app will send a string to the sMethod input parameter. Then the procedure will run queries based on the value of the sMethod. My problem is specifically inside MINPRC_STOCKMASTER. For whatever reason, this query causes the "lock wait timeout error"

I noticed that the query causing the lockup has a process ID that is 2 less than the update query, as seen in this picture: [image]

If I kill the process (so in this example, the one with ID 49036), then the update works, but another part of the web app will not update properly.

What's even weirder is that if I try to call the procedure directly, even that won't work. I end up getting disconnected from the database. Here is the query:

```
set @Result = '0';
set @Message = '0';
call inventorycontrol_ko_test.SP_TRX_DYNAMICPROD('MINPRC_STOCKMASTER','XA GEL','','','0','','','','BCST','BOT','60','admin',@Result,@Message);
select @Result, @Message;
```

And here is the error: [image]

I can call the procedure using other sMethods without any errors (ADD_PRDPRICE, UPDATE_PRDPRICE, etc.), MINPRC_STOCKMASTER specifically is the one that is causing problems.

So what I've tried:

- Killing process
- Sleeping before killing process
- Changing isolation level from REPEATABLE-READ to READ-COMMITTED
- Adding 'START TRANSACTION, FOR UPDATE, COMMIT' keywords for row-level locking
- Added an index on stk_stockcode

I don't know what to do from here. anyone got any ideas?

Comment: OK quick update, I can do the procedure call (inventorycontrol_ko_test.SP_TRX_DYNAMICPROD('MINPRC_STOCKMASTER') successfully, but still getting lock wait timeout errors when doing it through the webapp

Comment: OK, i actually managed to fix it. I needed to add "START TRANSACTION, COMMIT" to the query that updates stkm_stockmaster FIRST. Im updating this table twice actually, so committing the first query means the second query is able to update successfully.